# Injecting Store to sub classes using Injector angular 7

Tags: angular7, store, ngrx

I am injecting service from a super abstract class into our sub classes.
This works fine, except for the Store service.
What I'm doing is the following:

Super Class:

```
export abstract class GenericClass {
    translate: TranslateService;
    cdr: ChangeDetectorRef;
    someService: SomeService;
    otherService: OtherService; 
    anotherService: AnotherService;
    constructor(injector: Injector){
        this.translate = injector.get(TranslateService);
        this.cdr = injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef);
        this.someService= injector.get(SomeService);
        this.otherService = injector.get(OtherService);
        this.anotherService= injector.get(AnotherService);
    }
}
```

Sub-Class (Component):

```
export class SubClassComponent {
    constructor(injector: Injector){
       super(injector);
    }
}
```

This works fine, but with store it doesn't.
When I add Store the same way to the super class, e.g:

Super Class:

```
export abstract class GenericClass {
    ...
    store: Store<AppState>;
    constructor(injector: Injector){
        ...
        this.store = injector.get(Store<AppState>);
    }
}
```

In this case I get the following Error:

```
ERROR in fox-generic-form.ts(45,30): error TS2348: Value of type 'typeof Store' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?
```

I tried this with as it suggests in the error:

```
this.store = injector.get(new Store<AppState>);
```

How ever in this case I get an error on required arguments in the constructor of Store, and after checking it does require 3 different arguments:

store.d.ts:

```
constructor(state$: StateObservable, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: ReducerManager);
```

I've been searching for this for a while on the net and I can't find a solution, I did find testing scenarios, but those are not what I need for this case of components super-class & Injector.

Any one has an idea of how to use Store with Injector from a super class?
Or how I use these 3 arguments (state$: StateObservable, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: ReducerManager) with Store?

Comment: Could you find a solution for this problem? I am facing the same issues...

Comment: I'm sorry we have to another solution that doe's not include injecting to Sub classes. However you can try @timdeschryver solution.
I'm keeping this open so maybe can answer this.

Answer (score 2):

Should work if you would do `injector.get(Store)`, without the generic type.